# How to apply ordered values to the same BindingList?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have got:

```
var orderedStatItmes = item.Statistics.OrderByDescending(t=>t.StartTime);
```

Note that

```
public BindingList<IStatistics> Statistics { set; get; }
```

What I need is the best way to reassign `orderedStatItmes` to `item.Statistics` so it should be in *place*.

How to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: I might be missing something, but arent you already doing that?

Comment: What is type of `Statistic` and is it r/o or r/w property/field?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just updated the question. It is public BindingList<IStatistics> Statistics { set; get; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say I've used `BindingList<T>` much at all myself.

You may be better off sorting the underlying collection, if you've got access to that. Alternatively, if the `BindingList<T>` itself supports sorting, you might want to use [`IBindingList.ApplySort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.applysort).

One horribly hacky way of doing it would be:

```
var ordered = item.Statistics.OrderByDescending(t => t.StartTime).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < ordered.Count; i++)
{
    item.Statistics[i] = ordered[i];
}
```

... but I wouldn't like to say what that will do to any bindings while it's updating.

---

**Old answer** (before question was edited to mention `BindingList<T>`)

Do you mean you need to mutate the existing array, or are you happy to just assign a new array reference to the `item.Statistics` property? If it's the latter:

```
item.Statistics = item.Statistics.OrderByDescending(t=>t.StartTime).ToArray();
```

If you want to basically sort the array (I'm assuming it's an array, based on your question title) in place, you could use:

```
Array.Sort(item.Statistics, (x, y) => x.StartTime.CompareTo(y.StartTime));
```

Comment: Thanks! Could pls say how it should be if   public BindingList<IStatistics> Statistics { set; get; }

Comment: @Peretz: Well that's a very different matter. This is why it's important to be clear in your question, which doesn't mention `BindingList` at all, but *does* mention arrays. *Please* put more effort into your question next time. Now, do you need to edit the binding list *in place*, or could you create a new one? I don't know enough about `BindingList` to know the consequences of each choice.

Comment: "the binding list in place"  that's what I need. (I just updated my question)

Comment: @Peretz: You've updated your question in a way which doesn't make much sense, to be honest. If you assign a new value to `item.Statistics`, it *won't* be an in-place sort, pretty much by definition.